# R - avoiding loops with nested lists

Tags: r, nested

I know that for loops can be avoided almost all the time in R if you understand the language properly, but I'm struggling to find out the clever way of doing this

```
for (i in 1:100){
  AllData[[i]]$Div = NULL
}
```

Where AllData is a list of 100 lists of various sizes. Can someone clue me in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
AllData <- lapply(AllData, `[[<-`, "Div", NULL)
```

Comment: Isn't it possible without lapply?

Comment: What's wrong with it? It seems appropriate since you are working with a list.

Comment: There's nothing wrong, but it doesn't really further my understanding that much because it's so equivalent to my code. I might be looking for something that doesn't exist though, as I was expecting something like AllData[[1:100]] = NULL

Comment: I don't think you can, but let's wait and see. Also note that your `AllData[[1:100]] = NULL` does not mention `Div`.

Comment: The double square brackets operator `[[]]` for lists accepts only one element, so even ``AllData [[1:100]]$Div` will not work. For lists, `lapply` seems appropriate to me, too. However, if all list elements have elements of the same name, is list really the appropriate data type?

Comment: I'd probably go with `lapply`. However, I'm not sure here whether there is anything gained here that outweights the much better readability of the `for` loop. It is true that you should think carefully with loops in R, but there is no need to avoid them completely.

Comment: There is no increase in readability with a `for` loop unless you cannot read R.  A big purpose of apply is expressiveness and avoiding the typical tendency to write long `for` loops.  Just thinking of doing each step separately with a separate apply often provides performance boosts because somewhere in there you can get in a vectorized operation.

Comment: Interesting to investigate `system.time` of the two approaches, especially with an additional payload, e.g., `AllData <- replicate(10, list(list(Div=1, m=matrix(0, 1000, 10000))))`; the `for` loop is much faster.